# Writable store is overwritten on page change, SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, store, sveltekit, writable

I to values stored in a writable store

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const user = writable(null)
export const isLoggedIn = writable(false)
```

I then import these values from and set them in the index

```js
 import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
  import { user, isLoggedIn } from "../stores/authStore";
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  const auth = getAuth();
  function signIn() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        user.set(result.user) 
        isLoggedIn.set(true);
        console.log($isLoggedIn);
        console.log($user.email);
        if ($user.email.includes(".edu")) window.location.href = "/home";
        else window.location.href = "/Sorry";
        //sign user into db
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Someting wrong");
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

When I change page and print the values again using

```
console.log($userValue, $isLoggedIn)
```

It returns the default values of

```js
null false
```

I don't know if I'm using the wrong syntax or maybe I need to use cookies, but I am pretty nube at sveltekit and would love some help.

Answer (score 5):

Using `window.location.href = '/new-path';` causes your browser to make a full navigation away from the current page. It will unload the current page and load the new page instead, so any state you have on the current page will be lost (this includes variables and stores).

In SvelteKit, you can use the [`goto`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto) function to redirect your users. When used in the client, it'll trigger an in-page navigation via the client-side router, so you get to keep all your state:

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

if (someCondition) {
    goto('/home');
}
```